# How to serve messages properties both public, still access them from inside web project?

Tags: java, javascript, android, properties, playframework

**Background**

We have several clients, some is native as iPad and Android, other is html clients, like web and SmartTv.

We have a centralized web project that serve typical assets to all this clients, like icon, favicon, fonts and so on. In this way we can maintain assets in one place.

**Problem**

I now want to serve the messages property file, that is not public in the war file, to the JavaScript and the native clients.

Is there any good suggestion how to provide this messages public and in a proper format that fit the different clients?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the *#{i18n/}* tag as shown [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/tags#i18n). It will give you a javascript method that provides I18N translation of keys as defined in the *messages* file.

Comment: nice! at least that helps a lot on the JavaScript clients. I probably serialize the Messages as JSON for the native clients.

Answer (score 0):

One solution in Play! is to serve the messages to the public as json:

```
public class AssetsController extends Controller{

    public static void getMessages(){
        String locale = params.get("locale");
        if(locale == null){
            locale = Lang.get();
        }
        System.out.println(locale);
        Properties messages = Messages.all(locale);
        renderJSON(messages);
    }
}
```